# Disable digest email in Application insights

Tags: azure-application-insights

I'm using Application insights for outside-in testing, but my code is not instrumented with it. I don't want to receive the weekly email summary about my service, since most columns are blank.
How can I disable the email being sent? (Note I do not want to just unsubscribe myself from it)

Answer (score 3):

It appears this is not available yet, though someone has proposed it on the Application Insights uservoice site, and AI folks have commented on it:

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/357324-application-insights/suggestions/14444583-ability-to-disable-weekly-digest

I'd suggest upvoting that if you need it.

While not what you want, it looks like the only option at this time is to unsubscribe.

Answer (score 0):

As of 6/18/2018, application insights is no longer sending digest emails at all.

see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/automate-custom-reports for details, the suggestion is to use other tools, like Logic Apps or Flows to query and generate your own content.