# Disable weekly digest email for an environment in Application Insights

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I have 2 web apps in Azure, one for UAT and another for Production. Both have Application Insights telemetry installed and active on them for performance monitoring.

I currently am receiving the Weekly Application insights digest email, which summarizes the telemetry for the week, as expected. However both environments are included in the one email.

I do require to switch off this feature for the UAT web app. I have already disabled all alerts.

I have read the following post, [Disable digest email in Application insights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38318701/disable-digest-email-in-application-insights), but this is a request to unsubscribe from the email and not to disable for an environment.

[Disabled Alerts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jsJp.png)

Comment: Are you using one AI instance for both environments?

Comment: No I am using a different one for each environment. For example, myAppUAT-insights and myAppProd-insights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid it's not possible to explicitly disable AI(likewise it's not possible to disable storage account/event hub and so on).

If this is not a case you can stop sending the data to your AI instance, but still I'm not sure whether this is going to help you(by stop sending the data I mean - disable whole telemetry I avoid initializing it from your code).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately for now there is no way to selectively unsubscribe digest emails per application. We are planning to come up with a solution, but we cannot put a date on it yet.

Thanks,